# How do I switch between Java 7 and Java 6 on mac OS X 10.8.2?

Tags: java, preferences, osx-mountain-lion, java-7, java-6

I am using Java SE 7 to program simple games for windows and mac, but I have to switch to java 6 to run games such as Minecraft on my computer. This used to work just fine before I updated to Mac OS X 10.8.2 Build 12C60. Before this update I used to be able to open java preferences and check off java 6 or java 7. But now I don't seem to be able to find java preferences.

I am running mac OS X 10.8.2 (latest version)

Thanks.

Comment: You should be able to run Minecraft with Java 7...I do so all the time on my Linux box.

Comment: This question is not about programming at all, should be migrated to [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: well the error I am getting is: invalid java version....

Comment: Search for the Java Preferences application using spotlight then drag the version number you need to the top of the dialog which appears.  You will need to restart any application using Java to have this take effect.

Comment: I Couldn't even find it in the spotlight

Comment: Look in Applications/Utilities look for Java preferences. If it's not there, then it may have not being installed with lion

Comment: If this is a Minecraft issue, try updating your lwjgl with this: http://lwjgl.org/forum/index.php/topic,4711.msg25596.html#msg25596 -- Unfortunately the Java Preferences is now gone with the most recent Java update from Apple.

Comment: IMPORTANT: Apple made an update few days ago for 10.8.2 and removed Java Preferences - this question is more actual than it may seem at first sight!.